# Powershell Script to find the age of folder and presence

Tags: powershell

Created a PowerShell script to find the presence of Windows.old folder. Script will  check for the age of the folder is more than 14 days, If the folder is present. Then give an output as '1' if the age is more than 14 days. The output should be '0' if the age is less than 14 days. Also the script should give an output as '0' if the folder is not present.

Below is the script which I created where the first two conditions are working fine. For the third scenario, it's giving the output (0) as required but showing an error as shown. Do we have an option to get the output without the error message.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "C:\Windows.old"
$test = Test-Path $path
$task = ((Get-Item $path |
        Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }))
if ($test -eq $true) {
    if ($task) {
        $compliance ='1'
    } else {
        $compliance ='0'
    }
    $compliance
}
if ($test -eq $false) {
    Write-host '0'
}
```

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: move your `Get-Item` into the `if ($test -eq $True)` section. that will make sure that you only run the cmdlet when there is a valid target.

Comment: What is `$task = ((...))` supposed to accomplish? Could everybody please stop this useless use of parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i wrote a function that should do what you need

```
function Get-ItemTest(){
    Param(     
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [DateTime]$Limit
    )
    process{
        if(Test-Path $Path){
            Get-Item $path | %{
                if($_.Creationtime -lt $Limit){
                    new-object psobject -Property @{Name=$_.FullName;Compliance=1}
                }else{
                    new-object psobject -Property @{Name=$_.FullName;Compliance=0}
                }
            }
        }else{
            new-object psobject -Property @{Name=$Path;Compliance=0}
        }
        return $Response
    }
}

Get-ItemTest -Limit (get-date).AddDays(-15) -Path "C:\Windows"

"C:\Windows.old", "C:\Windows","C:\Users" | Get-ItemTest -Limit (get-date).AddDays(-15)
```

Lets go over what is happening here.

In your script

```
$task = ((Get-Item $path | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }))
```

you are already trying to get the Item before you test if the path is working. 
You can instead encapsulate that in a **IF** statement with **Test-Path**

```
if(Test-Path $Path){
    Get-Item ...
}else{
    "failed"
}
```